# WebApi Path differences when using RouteAttribute or implicit routing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, routes

I've been working with WebApi and I'm trying to understand how the difference in using the Route Attribute vs having WebApi automatically create the route based on the function name works. I have many controllers of this form:

```
public class MyController : RestControllerBase
{
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetData()
    {
        return _data;
    }

    [Route(ApiVersion.Version + "/MyController/{param}/specific/route")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetMoreData()
    {
        return _moreData;
    }
}
```

This controller and others all specify a route registry that does:

```
routingManager.RegisterVersionedHttpRoute(
                routeName: "MyController",
                routeTemplate: "MyController/{param}",
                defaults: new { controller = "MyController", param = RouteParameter.Optional },
                version: ApiVersion.Version);
```

When I build and test my API, both end points are correctly accessible.

I also overrode the HttpControllerSelector with one based on namespaces (for versioning).

My problem is that these two routes, besides the traditional function of being called by a specific http route, behave differently. For example, in my overridden controller selector I had to write this logic in order for the controllers and routes to properly map:

```
private string GetControllerName(IHttpRouteData routeData)
{
    if (routeData.GetSubRoutes() != null)
    {
        // With route attribute
        var subroute = routeData.GetSubRoutes().FirstOrDefault();
        var dataTokenValue = subroute.Route.DataTokens["actions"];
        if (dataTokenValue == null) return null;
        var controllername = ((HttpActionDescriptor[])dataTokenValue).First().ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName.Replace("Controller", string.Empty);
        return controllername;
    }
    else
    {
        // Try Strategy for without route attribute.
        return (String)routeData.Values["controller"];
    }
}

private string GetVersion(IHttpRouteData routeData)
{
    var routeTemplate = "";
    if (routeData.GetSubRoutes() != null)
    {
        var subRouteData = routeData.GetSubRoutes().FirstOrDefault();
        if (subRouteData == null) return null;
        routeTemplate = subRouteData.Route.RouteTemplate;
    }
    else
    {
        routeTemplate = routeData.Route.RouteTemplate;
    }

    var index = routeTemplate.IndexOf("/");
    if (index == -1)
    {
        return Unversioned;
    }
    var version = routeTemplate.Substring(0, index).ToUpperInvariant();
    return version;
}
```

It seems as though routes with the explicit attribute will have a route.GetSubroutes() available, whereas the implicit routes will not.
This causes me to write two different approaches to extracting the version and controller names from the incoming request before I can route them properly. I can live with that, but it really bothers me that something internal to WebApi is creating this distinction between the routes.

Unfortunately, I then started working with https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle to document my api and ran into similar issues. The swagger page generates correctly for routes that have the Route attribute, but completely ignores the implicit routes. I suspect the problem causing this issue is the same that causes the branch in my selecting logic.

I've been digging through as much ApiExplorer, WebAPI and other documentation as I can find online, but I haven't been able to find the solution to homogenize the implicit/explicit route approaches. It may even be a bug in their implementation.

Where should I go from here?

Answer (score 0):

So the answer here is that there is a bug or inconsistency with Web Api 2
To verify, you can run this code snippet. In the case I mentioned, ApiExplorer does not return results for paths that are not explicitedly marked with a route attribute.

```
        IApiExplorer apiExplorer = configuration.Services.GetApiExplorer();
        foreach (ApiDescription api in apiExplorer.ApiDescriptions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Uri path: {0}", api.RelativePath);
            Console.WriteLine("HTTP method: {0}", api.HttpMethod);
            foreach (ApiParameterDescription parameter in api.ParameterDescriptions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Parameter: {0} - {1}", parameter.Name, parameter.Source);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```